# How do I disable alpha combining of intersecting circles/polygons in Google Maps v3 API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a method/config property in the Google Maps v3 JS API to disable/workaround the alpha combining of overlapping circles? I'm currently working on a project that can end up drawing many circles on a map, with some areas being the intersection of >10 circles. Even with a very low opacity, this can soon make the map unreadable in those intersecting areas. Any suggestions on how to keep the intersections the same opacity as any individual circle would be much appreciated - apparently this was the default behaviour in v2 of the API (example screenshot:  http://img23.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110504at655.png/ )

Comment: image link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the paths, as arrays of arrays, into a single polygon. [**Example code here**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/poly/pentagon.html?r=40), and view the [**result here**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r40/trunk/poly/pentagon.html).

Comment: Perhaps a bit of a late comment, but I'm facing the same issue and I'm not exactly sure how this answer helps. Your example is of a polygon, not a bunch of circles...

Answer (score 0):

So 2 years later, I had the same issue.  This solution is a bit of a hack.

Set all the circles' opacity to 1 in the javascript.
Then add this css:

```
#map-canvas > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type  {
    opacity:0.3
}
```

If Google change the location of the circle layer, then this will break.
PS. I'm using v3 of the maps api.

Comment: They changed it.  Don't use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on Daryls answer you must put this into the style portion of the html header:

```
  .gm-style > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2){
  opacity: 0.1;
  }
```

This is working for me, as of july 2018